# how to create a sale form in yii2 where i can record multiple item in one sale

Tags: jquery, yii2, active-form

Am new to yii2 and am trying to create an ActiveForm in which I will be able to select multiple items and their quantity and be able to calculate the total amount because each item has a price.

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' =>['sales/create'], 'id' => 'new-sales',   'method'=>'post',]); ?>
<div class="container-fluid row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <?= 
           $form->field($model, 'product_name')
                 ->dropDownList(
                arrayHelper::map(Product::find()->all(),'product_name','product_name'),
            ['prompt' => 'Select product', 'class' => 'form-control text-center', 'id'=>'pname']
        ) ?> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'quantity')->textInput([
            'type' => 'number', 'min' => 1, 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'qnt'
        ]) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'amount')->textInput(['class'=> 'form-control']); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```